# How to avoid printing of the pages having "" in the cell in excel

Tags: excel, printing

I have created a spreadsheet where I have made the cells in a logic like this:

=if(logic,calculation,"")

I now am facing problem in printing the spreadsheet because all the cells with the value "" is printed in a blank page with nothing.

I want to print the cells only with the calculation not the blank cells.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to adjust the "" to an empty value, I'd suggest doing the following:
File, Options, Advanced, (about 2/3rds of the way down) check "Show Formulas in cells instead of their calculated values" and uncheck "Show a zero in cells that have zero value".
Or play with these two options for the results your looking for. 
I hope this helps!
Mikey

Comment: Hi Mikey.Thanks for your help. :( I'm still deleting the formluas before printing. I need an easy solution.

Comment: Rather than putting `""` as your false value, just leave it blank.
`=IF(logic, true, )`
If you adjust your options, they are user settings and will stick even after closing Excel, that should do the trick. If that doesn't help, maybe I don't understand the problem. Try to provide more details.